# Why is the Killing form the inverse of the quadratic Casimir invariant?

Tags: lie-algebras

Here's an excerpt from [this lecture script](http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs15/sym/SymHS15Notes.pdf):

[image]

And another one:

[image]

Why is there a relationship between the Killing form and the quadratic Casimir invariant?

Comment: Note that the $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ refers to the Cartan grading and assumes $\mathfrak{g}$ semisimple in the notes you quote.

Comment: @YCor I see. Well, it's a bit of a "maths for physicists" script, so it might well be that there are assumptions that are not written out. But do you understand why Killing forms and quadratic Casimir invariants are inversions of each other?